# Enforcing that childitems without language version are not returned

Tags: language-fallback

I have a menu container that contains link items. The menu container is just a container so it does not need to have separate versions in all the active site languages. More specifically, it will always only contain a version in english. The childitems however need to have separate versions in the active languages and there should be no language fallback if an item does not have a version in a language.

The code:

```
var mainMenuContainer = menuContainer.Children.FirstOrDefault(ch => ch.Name == MAINMENU_ITEMNAME);
```

So the mainMenuContainer will have the english language.

Then I do:

```
    var mainNavItems = mainMenuContainer.Children.Where(m => m.TemplateID == Constants.LinkItemTemplateId);
```

How could I enforce that this call only returns child items that have a version in the context language? Maybe I could do something like

```
 foreach (var language in item.Languages)
 {
     var langSpecificItem = MasterDb.GetItem(item.ID, language);

     if (langSpecificItem.HasVersion())
     {

     }
}
```

but this seems not to be a terribly efficient way. I see that I could also check the IsFallback property of each item, but that seems not to be very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mainNavItems = mainMenuContainer.Children.Where(m => m.TemplateID == Constants.LinkItemTemplateId && m.Versions.Count > 0);
```

Where: `m.Versions.Count > 0` is the new bit.

Items don't have language versions, only field values do. Add the above to your LINQ expression and you're good to go.

There is a new functionality, `EnforceVersionPresence` that also does this on a data layer level - but I highly recommend you do not use it. You'll basically have to "break off" your API from standard implementations to "Enforced" which could make it less portable.

Comment: If I add the m.Versions.Count clause, I still get the fallback items. The strange thing is that the language of the item returned is non-english for which there is no version in sitecore but item.Version.Count = 1 for the returned item. So the .Version.Count is read from the fallback item, it seems..

Comment: Oh so you ARE using fallbacks?

Comment: Yes, I have enableItemLanguageFallback=true for the website. But I do want to override this behaviour.